# Dictionary with values dependent on / linked to values of another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dependencies

I need to create a dictionary with values dependent on / linked to values of another dictionary in Python.

Minimum working example:

```
from pprint import pprint
import os

miscellaneous = {'input_dir': "Results/Job_test/Input/",
                 'output_dir': "Results/Job_test/Output/",
                 'file_name_basis': "truss",
                 'file_name_extension_input': ".input",
                 'file_name_extension_output': ".output",
                 'screen_width_to_height_ratio': 16 / 9}

postprocessing = {'archive': {'execute': False,
                              'type': 'xztar',
                              'file_name_basis': miscellaneous['file_name_basis'],
                              'file_name_extension': ".tar.xz",
                              'output_dir': miscellaneous['output_dir'],
                              'directory_to_archive': "."}}

# Input_definition, final assembly.
input_def = {'miscellaneous': miscellaneous,
             'postprocessing': postprocessing}

pprint(input_def)
miscellaneous.update({'output_dir': "I_made_it/"})
print("================================================================================")
pprint(input_def)  # Only input_def['miscellaneous']['output_dir'] changed, but not input_def['postprocessing']['archive']['output_dir'].
```

What should I change such that not only `input_def['miscellaneous']['output_dir']` changes to `I_made_it/` but also `input_def['postprocessing']['archive']['output_dir']` changes to `I_made_it/`?

Comment: Hey Adriaan, was my answer helpful, or are you still having trouble? 
If so, please accept it so the question will become closed.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `'output_dir': miscellaneous['output_dir'],` in the deceleration and definition of `postprocessing` is evaluated at assignment - the state is not preserved.

In order to have state you can use Objects. A small working example might be:

```
class MyOutputDir(object):
    outputDir = ""

outputDirInstance = MyOutputDir()
outputDirInstance.outputDir = "This is one value"

d1 = {"o1": outputDirInstance}

d2 = {"o1": d1["o1"]}

print(d2["o1"].outputDir)
# prints: 'This is one value'

d2["o1"].outputDir = "Another, newer value"

print(d1["o1"].outputDir)
# prints: 'Another, newer value'
```

To read more about classes and objects in python see https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html: There might be more info there which you might find useful, as it seems you are "streching" the limit of what should be done with dicts (which are DATA) and you should probably consider a more Object-Oriented approach.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use objects in python. This should do it if I didn't miss anything.

```py
from pprint import pprint
import os

class the_directories:
    __init__(self):
        self.out = "Results/Job_test/Output/"
        self.in_d = "Results/Job_test/Input/"

dir = the_directories()

miscellaneous = {'input_dir': dir.in_d,
                 'output_dir' dir.out: ,
                 'file_name_basis': "truss",
                 'file_name_extension_input': ".input",
                 'file_name_extension_output': ".output",
                 'screen_width_to_height_ratio': 16 / 9}

postprocessing = {'archive': {'execute': False,
                              'type': 'xztar',
                              'file_name_basis': miscellaneous['file_name_basis'],
                              'file_name_extension': ".tar.xz",
                              'output_dir': dir.out,
                              'directory_to_archive': "."}}

# Input_definition, final assembly.
input_def = {'miscellaneous': miscellaneous,
             'postprocessing': postprocessing}

pprint(input_def)
dir.out = "I_made_it/"
print("================================================================================")
pprint(input_def)  # Only input_def['miscellaneous']['output_dir'] changed, but not input_def['postprocessing']['archive']['output_dir'].
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my answer is better than any others but this might be what you expect.

You could map 'output_dir' to dictionary which will be evaluated later. Although, this might lead to changing of your dictionary structure. It looks wired that you mapped to whole dictionary and mapped to one field again.

```
postprocessing = {'archive': {'execute': False,
                              'type': 'xztar',
                              'file_name_basis': miscellaneous['file_name_basis'],
                              'file_name_extension': ".tar.xz",
                              'output_dir': miscellaneous,
                              'directory_to_archive': "."}}
```

Long term, you should try object.